# hi, I am using Django Framework I want to check if the mobile-no is in the database or not but I have error

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am using Django Framework I want to check if the mobile-no is in the database but I have error  when I run the code it gives me only False even when the number is exist in database it gives me False can someone help me this is my code

views.py

```
@csrf_exempt
def forget_password(request):
    mobile_no = request.POST.get('mobile_no')
    # verify = models.User.objects.all()
    # verify = models.User.objects.filter(mobile_no=mobile_no).first()
    verify = models.User.objects.filter(mobile_no=mobile_no).exists()
    if verify:
        return JsonResponse({'bool':True})
    else:
        return JsonResponse({'bool':False,'msg' : 'mobile_no does not exist!!'})
```

Comment: It could be type casting issue, check if the mobile no's type is correct one or not from DRF.

Comment: I do not know why it is not working for me

Comment: I am using this in my models.py mobile_no=models.CharField(max_length=200,blank=True) –

Comment: I suggest debugging the issue. Put a debugger to see what input you get from request.POST

Comment: I checked every time the post data gives null because of that it gives me false but I do not know why it gives me null

Comment: then print request.POST to see what data you are getting.

Comment: when I print the verify it gives me False I do not know what is this false

Comment: but when I print mobile_no it gives me None

Comment: print request.POST

Comment: this is the print of request.POST <QueryDict: {}>

Comment: It means you are not getting any data on POST request. How are you making request? Forms or API?

Comment: I am using API to get the request

Comment: can you check if `request.data` works?

Comment: how can I check it? can you help me

Comment: print(request.data)

Comment: I print request.data it gives me this <QueryDict: {}>

Comment: Well, then I am afraid, this is not a django issue. Rather you are not sending the data correctly via API.

Comment: I think the data should not be in JSON type because I am sending the data in JSON format but how can I know which data type should I send

Answer (score 0):

As mobile no. for each user is unique, use following view:

```py
from django.views.decorators.http import require_POST

@require_POST
@csrf_exempt
def forget_password(request):
    mobile_no = request.POST.get('mobile_no')
    try:    
        models.User.objects.get(mobile_no=mobile_no)
        return JsonResponse({'bool':True})
    except models.User.DoesNotExist:
        return JsonResponse({'bool':False,'msg' : 'mobile_no does not exist!!'})
```

Comment: it does not work I do not know why it is not working

Comment: @BawarRwandzy can you share your html, maybe you should use `@require_post` decorator.

Comment: I am using Flutter not html and know I am using postman to test it and I do not know if the error is because of that or not

Comment: I am using this in my models.py mobile_no=models.CharField(max_length=200,blank=True)

Answer (score 0):

try This code I think you do a mistake in importing User model

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
@csrf_exempt
def forget_password(request):
    mobile_no = request.POST.get('mobile_no')
    verify = User.objects.filter(mobile_no=mobile_no)
    if verify.exists():
        return JsonResponse({'bool':True})
    else:
        return JsonResponse({'bool':False,'msg' : 'mobile_no does not exist!!'})
```

Comment: it give me this error     raise AttributeError(
AttributeError: Manager isn't available; 'auth.User' has been swapped for 'main.User'
[09/Jan/2023 16:02:06] "POST /api/forget-password/ HTTP/1.1" 500 71364